Weight transfer just sets everything to 0.5 on a single bone
I'm trying to attach clothing to my rigged character. I'm doing what every guide has told me to do (start with empty groups on the clothing mesh, select the character mesh, select the clothing mesh, transfer weights, set the source layer to "by name"), but the mesh just moves in one big piece, uniformly attached to one single bone.
I've tried using the data transfer modifier. I've tried playing with the ray radius in the weight transfer. I've tried changing the vertex mapping options. I always either get the same result, or no result at all.
I'm using Blender 4.1
videos of the issue
.blend file

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

@Jakemoyo Done. I hope google drive is alright

Hi. Is this the right blend file? There is no armature and the model has no weights/vertex groups at all.

@Blunder Really? I may have accidentally sent an earlier version. I've updated the link.

The only mesh that seems to have any blatant issue is waistcoar.003, but both using the data transfer or adding a simple data transfer modifier as you described does quite a good job already: https://i.imgur.com/IoUzL4D.png After that it's just a bit of touching up to fix small issues, but nothing like the issues you mention.

Perhaps try on Blender 4.2, it's been out for a few days, maybe it's an old bug that is now fixed. On a different note: I hope you know that the metarig object provided by rigify isn't meant to be the actual animation rig, it's a placement tool to generate the full feature rig. You will suffer in animation if you try using that metarig as is.

@Lauloque Oh, I know. I don't like rigify's rigs, but I use their ORG bones as a quick base point before manually adding my own controls

@Lauloque Would you look at that! Updating made it work! Thank you so much!
